# Need to split string by "," but not by "\," using regular expressions

Tags: c#

something like this [^\][,] divides the string as needed, but removes the last character.
String example: Id=000243DE,Price=0,Weight=1,Author=Mar\,obar Sul,Skill=Athletics;"
https://regex101.com/r/PxbTYd/24

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Also not present is any attempt made on your part in solving the problem. Lastly, `\,` is not a valid escape sequence.

Comment: In case you weren't aware, the usual way of including the separator character in a CSV item is to enclose the item in double-quotes, like `a,b,"c,d",e`.

Comment: I seems, you want to escape the separator character `, ` by a backslash. A complete escaping rule also has to specify what to do if the escape character itself is present in the original string. So how would @"A\B,C" be esacped? As @"A\\B\,C"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for a comma, but not if it is preceded by a slash:

```
(?<!\\),
```

The thing in brackets is a negative lookbehind - if a slash is present it causes matching the comma to fail. The slash is doubled as an escape. If you're putting this into a C# string you'll need a normal string with 4 slashes, or an @string with 2 slashes

Comment: Note that this will also not match `\\,` - the specification of the escaping-rule in the question is incomplete in this respect.